# sorting list numerically based from column from file

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am basically using a text file to store the scores to be used with leaderboards. The scores text file has 3 columns: levelname, username, score.

This is an example from by database:

```
level1, Bobby, 20
level1, connor, 33
level3, connor, 5
level1, Sam , 40
level2, connor, 80
level2, Bobby, 66
level3, Sam, 12
level2, Sam, 10
level3, bobby, 17
```

I want it to show one level at a time. e.g: only show: level1, username, scores.

I then want it to order the scores to ascending order.
I'm using pygame so there may be random code.
Heres what I have so far:

```
f = open("scores.txt", "r")
f1 = f.readlines()    
f.close()
currentlevel = level2

for line in f1:   
    linesplit = line.split(',')
    if linesplit[0] == currentlevel: 
        g.makecentretext(line, white, i, 30)     #Print line basically, just method to print line
```

This prints the correct level off, but will not display the lines in order of the third column. I have attempted to use `sort()` to fix this but it does not work. Can someone help me please?
thank you

Comment: please provide the expected output

Answer (score 2):

You can save your leaderboard instead of going line by line, and then sort it with a costume key - first by the level and then by the score:

```py
with open("scores.txt") as f:
    leaderboard = [line.strip().split(', ') for line in f]

leaderboard.sort(key=lambda line: (line[0], int(line[2])))

for entry in leaderboard:
    print(*entry)
```

This will give:

```
level1 Bobby 20
level1 connor 33
level1 Sam  40
level2 Sam 10
level2 Bobby 66
level2 connor 80
level3 connor 5
level3 Sam 12
level3 bobby 17
```

---

Similarly, if you want to take one level at a time, you can [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) the full leaderboard to a specific level and then sort that level:

```py
with open("scores.txt") as f:
    leaderboard = [line.strip().split(', ') for line in f]

currentlevel = 'level2'
level_scores = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == currentlevel, leaderboard))
# can be also achieved with a simple list-comprehension: 
# level_scores = [entry for entry in leaderboard if entry[0] == currentlevel]
level_scores.sort(key=lambda line: int(line[2]))

for entry in level_scores:
    print(*entry)
```

And this will give:

```
level2 Sam 10
level2 Bobby 66
level2 connor 80
```